# Prove that symmetric difference of two perfect matchings is union of disjoint even cycles

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, discrete-optimization, matching-theory

**Problem:** Let $M$ and $N$ be perfect matchings of a finite graph $G$. Prove that their symmetric difference is a union of disjoint even cycles.

**My attempt:**

Firstly, if $M = N$, we are done.

Now, let us consider the case when $M \neq N$. Since $M$ and $N$ are perfect matchings of $G$ then $d(v) \ge 2$ for any $v \in V$. Let $e = (u,v)$ be the edge in $M \setminus N$. Since $N$ is a perfect matching then there exists a vertex $v' \in N$ such that $(v,v') \in N\setminus M$. If we keep doing like this, we will obtain a cycle. But, I do not know how to write it down. I hope you could help me with this.

Comment: A way to see it is because the symmetric difference is $S:= M \cup N \setminus M \cap N$, all the degrees of vertices in the subgraph induced by edges in $S$, say $H$, must have degree $\leq 2$. The crux of the question is to show that if a vertex is not isolated, then it has degree $2$ in $H$ (i.e. there is no vertex of degree $1$). Once you are done with this, it is not hard to see that $2$-regular graphs are disjoint union of cycles, and the reason why all the cycles have even length is because every cycle will alternate between edges in $M$ and $N$.

Comment: @koifish Thank you a lot! I understand your idea. I will post the answer below soon.